# HTTPS Post using Excel VBA with XML body and request headers issue

Tags: excel, xml, vba, http

I am trying to use Excel-VBA to perform an https POST of an XML body as follows:

```vb
Public Sub test()
Dim xmlhttp As Object
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
Dim myDom As Object
Set myDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

URL = "https://uatgateway.topl.com.au/quote"
myDom.async = False
myXMLstr = URL & "<?xml version=&Chr(34)&1.0&Chr(34)& encoding=&Chr(34)&UTF- 
8&Chr(34)& standalone=&Chr(34)&yes&Chr(34)&?><IMPULSE><REQUEST><QUOTE> 
<MERCHANT><ACQUIRERID>Bank A</ACQUIRERID><NETWORKID>eComm</NETWORKID> 
<MERCHANTID>987654321</MERCHANTID></MERCHANT><MCH_TRANSACTION> 
<QUOTEREF>3456789012</QUOTEREF><MCH_ISO>036</MCH_ISO> 
<MCH_AMT>1000.00</MCH_AMT><BIN>400555000</BIN></MCH_TRANSACTION></QUOTE> 
</REQUEST></IMPULSE>"

myDom.Load (myXMLstr)

xmlhttp.Open "post", URL, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "356"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/xml"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Host", "uatgateway.topl.com.au"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"

xmlhttp.send myDom.XML
MsgBox xmlhttp.responseText
End Sub
```

My VBA code compiles ok, but on execution stops at the xmlhttp.send line almost immediately with an error "the server returned an invalid or unrecognised response". The same POST on Postman works. I am not sure if I an referencing the myDom.XML correctly?

Any suggestions welcome?

Comment: Think you need to look at your `myXMLstr`, your VBA code/functions are being interpreted as literal strings as everything is between double quotes (from what I can see).

Comment: Also, you seem to be prepending the URL to the beginning of your XML document, which itself does not presently seem to be valid (see previous comment). Could you post the successful request in Postman, so that it's clear whether the body should begin with a URL? Thanks

Comment: You might need to change your `myXMLstr` assignment to `myXMLstr = URL & "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) &  "encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & "standalone=" & Chr(34) & "yes" & Chr(34) & "?><IMPULSE><REQUEST><QUOTE> 
<MERCHANT><ACQUIRERID>Bank A</ACQUIRERID><NETWORKID>eComm</NETWORKID> 
<MERCHANTID>987654321</MERCHANTID></MERCHANT><MCH_TRANSACTION> 
<QUOTEREF>3456789012</QUOTEREF><MCH_ISO>036</MCH_ISO> 
<MCH_AMT>1000.00</MCH_AMT><BIN>400555000</BIN></MCH_TRANSACTION></QUOTE></REQUEST></IMPULSE>"` -- something like that, though it's possible the URL should not be in it

Comment: Hi chillin ...thanks, you're right about the myXMLstr assignment and removing the URL prependment. But also, I needed to use the LoadXML method of the DOMdocument model instead of the Load method. That's because I am loading the XML as a string and not as a resource pointing to the XML string. Fixing all these means it is now working ...so many thanks for the tips!